# Pass value/variable from HTML to JS file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**My code now ( in same .html file ):**

```
<div id="name">my_name</div>

<script>
    alert($("#name").text());
</script>
```

this works...

but I want to store this script in a different .js file like...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/name.js"></script>

<div id="name">my_name</div>
```

expectation to alert *'my_name'*

Comment: Try to use `ready()` to make a function available after the document is loaded. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp or https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

It work but you need to use jQuery in function like this :

```
$(function() {
    alert($("#name").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://filebin.net/t8bnvjrt4u4xkezj/test.js?t=2ilgo334"></script>

<div id="name">my_name</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**My bad..**

*importing at end works*

```
<div id="name">my_name</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/name.js"></script>
```